# How to copy folders from a network share using an UWP application in Windows 10

Tags: uwp

I have a very simple UWP application in windows 10 and i want to copy several folders of data from a network share like //192.168.1.10/public/ to my local application folder.

I did this,
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\172.20.3.209\public");

based upon my readings over the blog  gave permissions like in the Package.appxmanifest add the Capabilities revolving arund: Internet, Private Networks, Proximity, Enterprise Authentification.

I don't know what to do next, please help me if you have a subsequent method to copy a set of folders from the remote shares. thanks

Regards
JK

Comment: Did you add the required file type associations to your app manifest as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to copy folders from a network share using an UWP application in Windows 10

UWP has provided [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) capability to access broader file with APIs in the `Windows.Storage namespace`. You need add the restricted `broadFileSystemAccess` capability before access.

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

...
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: This worked, and additionally i have followed the below blog details to match my Windows Target version,https://www.jocheojeda.com/2019/01/26/xamarin-forms-uwp-uap-broad-file-system-access/

Comment: Yep, if you want, you could add the blog's link to my answer.